# hg ignore for VC6 projects

Tags: c++, mercurial, visual-c++-6, hgignore

What is the best hgignore list for VC6 projects? it's kind of old and I can't google it.

I found there was a list for VS2010 and VS2008, but the project files are totally different.

Comment: Mercurial was only released in 2005, by which date VC6 was already obsolete. You're probably better off migrating to a 21st century VC version.

Comment: It's pretty easy to figure out.  Create a new project but don't build it.  Check in all the files.  Build both the debug and release versions.  Ignore the new generated files.  Use patterns like "Debug/", "Release/" for blanket ignore of whole directories, and "*.xxx" for generated extensions.

Comment: @MarkTolonen VC6 has some aps, clw, ncb opt plg Files, and will change since I open the project, won't change if I build or not build it.

Comment: If they change without you editing them, they are generated and shouldn't be checked in.  Use `hg forget` on them and add them to the ignore list.  Now you have a basic ignore file.  If I remember correctly, all those listed should be in your ignore list.  The will be regenerated when you open your source again if missing.  Experiment on a new throw-away project.